# Window.open() in GWT opening file

Tags: java, eclipse, google-chrome, firefox, gwt

I'm trying to run this code

```
String outputFile = "file:///C:/reports/1016.html";
Window.open(outputFile, "Test", "");
Window.open("http://www.bing.com/", "bing", "");
```

As you can see, outputFile is not a weblink, but a file. Chrome/firefox do not seem to want to open it, they keep opening an about:blank window. I thought I had done it wrong so I added the third line with an actual webaddress which works fine. What am I doing wrong here? can Window.open() not open files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it is for security reasons.

Try to start chrome browser with disabled security and see what happens:

```
chromium --disable-web-security
```

If the local file is shown, you know its for security reasons disabled. (And you can nothing do against it).

Maybe the web debugger shows a warning (`F12`)

Answer (score 0):

To add to Christian Kuetbach's answer:

1. Most browsers will block it for security reasons except when coming directly from a click event. (Can't find a link supporting that assertion at the moment but it's worth a try)

   Try to Window.open from a user click and it should work.
2. It should be okay when opening a window in the same website (Same origin policy)
   See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.open

EDIT: For #1:
['window.open' blocked by Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10471595/window-open-blocked-by-firefox) and
https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/pop-blocker-settings-exceptions-troubleshooting?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=Pop-up+blocker
says:

> *Is the pop-up shown after a mouse click or a key press?*
>
> Certain events, such as clicking or pressing a key, can spawn pop-ups
> regardless of if the pop-up blocker is on. This is so that Firefox
> doesn't block pop-ups that websites need to work.