# how to initialize fullscreen without user interaction

Tags: javascript, css, html, firefox

Hi i'm beginner and i want to create a web-app and needs help in fullscreen when page is Load... without user interaction

I have something like this at the click function works correctly... but i want to load function at the start page

```
addEventListener("click", function() 
    {
        var el = document.documentElement , rfs = el.requestFullScreen ||
        el.webkitRequestFullScreen || el.mozRequestFullScreen ;
        rfs.call(el);
    });
```

Someone help me :)

Thank you!

Comment: Check [DOMContentLoaded](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/DOMContentLoaded). You may also try `(function(){/*Your code to full screen*/})();`

Comment: Thank you for advice. I checked "DOMContentLoaded" with my code... Function doesn't work :(. When replace any other code for example
"function myFunction() { alert("Hello"); } " it works...............Why is this happening?

Comment: you cannot force the user to go fullscreen without a user action

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is not possible.

I ran the following snippet in my browser console:

```
var e = document.getElementById('answers');
(e.webkitRequestFullScreen || e.mozRequestFullScreen).apply(e);
```

Chrome told me:

> Failed to execute 'requestFullScreen' on 'Element': API can only be initiated by a user gesture.

Firefox told me:

> Request for full-screen was denied because Element.mozRequestFullScreen() was not called from inside a short running user-generated event handler.

That is a restriction put in place to prevent abuse, similar to that on `window.open` (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10471595/2302862) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6192889/2302862) question for example).

Comment: Is it possible to use something like puppeteer to mimic such a behavior?

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me, but by rotating the phone on landscape or portrait mode.

```
window.screen.orientation.onchange = function() {

      if (this.type.startsWith('landscape')) {
        document.documentElement.webkitRequestFullscreen();
      } else {
        document.webkitExitFullscreen();
      }

};
```

Comment: Rotating phone is also a user gesture. So this doesn't actually solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

There is one solution to do this. If you are trying things for personal projects then it might be helpful.

***Note : This is not good Security Practice.**

You can follow following steps only on Firefox to allow full-screen without user interactions :

1. Open new tab in Firefox and type 'about:config'
2. You will see warning message. Click "I accept the risk!" button to proceed.
3. In the search box type 'full-screen-api.allow-trusted-requests-only'
4. Double click on the 'full-screen-api.allow-trusted-requests-only' entry to toggle its value.
   Now it will set to false and you will not get the error 'not called from inside a short running user-generated event handler'.

*Note : Malicious websites could exploit this setting to take control of your screen and trap you in full-screen mode. After doing experiments you can turn it on.

Hope this will be helpful...!

Answer (score -1):

You try this.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('html').click(function () {
        if (screenfull.isFullscreen !== true) {
            screenfull.toggle();
        }
    });
});
```

jQuery plugin

```
/*!
 * screenfull
 * v3.0.0 - 2015-11-24
 * (c) Sindre Sorhus; MIT License
 */
!function () {
    "use strict";
    var a = "undefined" != typeof module && module.exports, b = "undefined" != typeof Element && "ALLOW_KEYBOARD_INPUT"in Element, c = function () {
        for (var a, b, c = [["requestFullscreen", "exitFullscreen", "fullscreenElement", "fullscreenEnabled", "fullscreenchange", "fullscreenerror"], ["webkitRequestFullscreen", "webkitExitFullscreen", "webkitFullscreenElement", "webkitFullscreenEnabled", "webkitfullscreenchange", "webkitfullscreenerror"], ["webkitRequestFullScreen", "webkitCancelFullScreen", "webkitCurrentFullScreenElement", "webkitCancelFullScreen", "webkitfullscreenchange", "webkitfullscreenerror"], ["mozRequestFullScreen", "mozCancelFullScreen", "mozFullScreenElement", "mozFullScreenEnabled", "mozfullscreenchange", "mozfullscreenerror"], ["msRequestFullscreen", "msExitFullscreen", "msFullscreenElement", "msFullscreenEnabled", "MSFullscreenChange", "MSFullscreenError"]], d = 0, e = c.length, f = {}; e > d; d++)
            if (a = c[d], a && a[1]in document) {
                for (d = 0, b = a.length; b > d; d++)
                    f[c[0][d]] = a[d];
                return f;
            }
        return!1;
    }(), d = {request: function (a) {
            var d = c.requestFullscreen;
            a = a || document.documentElement, /5\.1[\.\d]* Safari/.test(navigator.userAgent) ? a[d]() : a[d](b && Element.ALLOW_KEYBOARD_INPUT);
        }, exit: function () {
            document[c.exitFullscreen]();
        }, toggle: function (a) {
            this.isFullscreen ? this.exit() : this.request(a);
        }, raw: c};
    return c ? (Object.defineProperties(d, {isFullscreen: {get: function () {
                return Boolean(document[c.fullscreenElement]);
            }}, element: {enumerable: !0, get: function () {
                return document[c.fullscreenElement]
            }}, enabled: {enumerable: !0, get: function () {
                return Boolean(document[c.fullscreenEnabled]);
            }}}), void(a ? module.exports = d : window.screenfull = d)) : void(a ? module.exports = !1 : window.screenfull = !1);
}();
```

Comment: A click (`$('html').click`) is a user interaction.